# System.Argument.Exception error when I try to call it in Button_Click method C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

When I try to execute the code below in MainPage Constructor it works perfectly. But when I put the same code under some Button_Click Method it gives me an error in - Stack1.Children.Add(shuffleRadio[1]);

Its a quiz with random option generating and in-code radio button generating.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        questions = questionset.ToList<String>();
        answers = answerset.ToList<String>();
        try
        {


            tr = randomizer.Next(4);
            que.Text = questions[tr].ToString();
            questions.RemoveAt(tr);

            RadioButton ra1 = new RadioButton();
            ra1.Name = "ans1";
            ra1.Content = answers[tr].ToString();
            ra1.GroupName = "Group1";
            ra1.Checked += RadioButton_Checked;
            answers.RemoveAt(tr);

            RadioButton ra2 = new RadioButton();
            rand = randomizer.Next(5);
            ra2.Name = "ans1";
            ra2.Content = answers[rand].ToString();
            ra2.GroupName = "Group1";
            ra2.Checked += RadioButton_Checked;
            answers.RemoveAt(rand);

            RadioButton ra3 = new RadioButton();
            rand = randomizer.Next(3);
            ra3.Name = "ans1";
            ra3.Content = answers[rand].ToString();
            ra3.GroupName = "Group1";
            ra3.Checked += RadioButton_Checked;
            answers.RemoveAt(rand);

            RadioButton ra4 = new RadioButton();
            rand = randomizer.Next(2);
            ra4.Name = "ans1";
            ra4.Content = answers[rand].ToString();
            ra4.GroupName = "Group1";
            ra4.Checked += RadioButton_Checked;
            answers.RemoveAt(rand);

            List<RadioButton> shuffleRadio = new List<RadioButton>();
            shuffleRadio.Add(ra1);
            shuffleRadio.Add(ra2);
            shuffleRadio.Add(ra3);
            shuffleRadio.Add(ra4);

            Random rng = new Random();
            int r = shuffleRadio.Count;
            while (r > 1)
            {
                r--;
                int tem = rng.Next(r + 1);
                RadioButton value = shuffleRadio[tem];
                shuffleRadio[tem] = shuffleRadio[r];
                shuffleRadio[r] = value;
            }


            Stack1.Children.Add(shuffleRadio[0]);
            Stack1.Children.Add(shuffleRadio[1]);     //The error is here
            Stack1.Children.Add(shuffleRadio[2]);
            Stack1.Children.Add(shuffleRadio[3]);

        }
        catch (Exception erg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(erg.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the content I was adding in stackpanel become duplicate of previous so

```
 foreach (var itm in shuffleRadio)
            {
                RadioButton ra = new RadioButton();
                ra.Content = itm.Content.ToString();
                ra.GroupName = "Group1";
                ra.Checked += RadioButton_Checked;
                Stack1.Children.Add(ra);
            }
```